# PHP - How can I remove the last PHP_EOL (because it is empty) in file?

Tags: php, html, css

I retrieve an information from database and have to store it in a text file. But when I store the information in the last row in the document there is empty line. How can I remove this empty line?
My code is:

```
while ($info = mysqli_fetch_assoc($takeInfo)) {
    $two = '2';
    $dateCreate = date("d.m.Y", strtotime($info['dateSystavqne']));
    $docNumber = $info['docNumber'];
    $typeDoc = $info['typeDoc'];
    //try to save the file!
    $content = $two.'|'.$dateCreate.'|'.$docNumber.PHP_EOL;
    file_put_contents('files/data.txt', $content, FILE_APPEND);
}
```

The information from the file is:

- 2|03.01.2017|0000016400
- 2|03.01.2017|0000016401
- 2|03.01.2017|0000016402
- 2|03.01.2017|0000016403
- 2|03.01.2017|0000016404
- 2|03.01.2017|0000016405
- //here is an empty
  line! How can I remove it?

Comment: Have you tried `trim($content)` before you output it? It will trim from the string beginning too tho.

Answer (score 2):

You can collect the rows into an array, implode them and write the result into the file:

```
$content = [];
while ($info = mysqli_fetch_assoc($takeInfo)) {
  // ...
  $content[] = $two . '|' . $dateCreate . '|' . $docNumber;
}

$content = implode(PHP_EOL, $content);
file_put_contents('files/data.txt', $content, FILE_APPEND);
```

This will consume more memory, but will reduce the number of I/O operations, obviously. This solution is acceptable for relatively small result sets. For a big number of rows you will need to flush contents of the array into the file periodically. One of the simplest ways is to flush the contents of the array into the file when the number of items becomes larger than some limit, e.g.:

```
$fh = fopen('files/data.txt', 'a');

$content = [];
for ($i = 1; $info = mysqli_fetch_assoc($takeInfo); $i++) {
  // ...
  $content[] = $two . '|' . $dateCreate . '|' . $docNumber;

  if (count($content) >= 1e3) {
    $content = implode(PHP_EOL, $content);

    if ($takeInfo->num_rows > $i)
      $content .= PHP_EOL;

    fwrite($fh, $content);
    $content = [];
  }
}

if ($content) {
  $content = implode(PHP_EOL, $content);
  fwrite($fh, $content);
  $content = null;
}

fclose($fh);
```

Note, you can get the number of records in the result set with [`mysqli_result::$num_rows`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php) property.

Comment: It is worked - this code remove the last empty line! BUT it is also remove the line 2|03.01.2017|0000016401! Why?

Comment: @BorislavRazvanski, probably because the result set had no such row in it. Try to write the rows into another file in parallel, then compare the two files with `diff file1 file2` command, for instance. If the difference is only the newline character, then the algorithm works as expected.

Comment: @BorislavRazvanski, I'm glad that it worked as you expected. Please accept the answer, if it solves the problem.